# Uploading both original and resized images with ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to get my app to both save in the server the resized image and the original file.

This is what I've tried so far:

HTML:

```
<a ng-model="originalPic" 
   ngf-select="uploadphototest($file)" 
   ngf-resize="{width: 1170, type: 'image/jpeg'}" 
   ngf-resize-if="$width > 1000"
   ngf-model-options="{updateOn: 'change drop paste'}" 
   ngf-fix-orientation="true">
      Upload image
</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.uploadphototest = function (file) {
  $scope.fileext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'), file.name.length);
  $scope.uniqueportrait = $scope.fairnameonly + "-" + moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY-HH-mm-ss') + $scope.fileext;

  Upload.imageDimensions(file).then(function(dimensions){
    if (dimensions.width < 1170){
      $scope.sizeerror = true;

    }else{

      fileor = $scope.originalPic;

      Upload.upload({
        url: 'uploadtest.php',
        data: {
          file: file,
          name: Upload.rename(file, $scope.uniqueportrait),
          fileor: fileor,
        }
      }).then(function (resp) {
         ...
      });
    };
  });
};
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $destination = '/home/clients/cc5399b00bc00f15dc81742a0369c7b8/discovery/register/uploadstest/' . $filename;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $destination );

    $filenameor = "ORIGINAL".$_FILES['fileor']['name'];
    $destinationor = '/home/clients/cc5399b00bc00f15dc81742a0369c7b8/discovery/register/uploadstest/' . $filenameor;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileor']['tmp_name'] , $destinationor ); 
?>
```

So far is going through but only uploading the resized one, the original one seems not to pass from the model to the function, as the model comes back undefined in the console...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Upload.resize` service of the library. Do not use `ngf-resize` and`gf-resize-if` in your HTML but resize the file in your JS. Something like:

HTML:

```
<a ng-model="originalPic" 
   ngf-select="uploadphototest($file)" 
   ngf-model-options="{updateOn: 'change drop paste'}" 
   ngf-fix-orientation="true">
      Upload image
</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.uploadphototest = function (file) {
  $scope.fileext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'), file.name.length);
  $scope.uniqueportrait = $scope.fairnameonly + "-" + moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY-HH-mm-ss') + $scope.fileext;

  Upload.imageDimensions(file).then(function(dimensions){
    if (dimensions.width < 1170){
        $scope.sizeerror = true;
    } else if(dimensions.width > 1000){
        var resizeOptions = {
            width: 1170
        };

        Upload.resize(file, resizeOptions).then(function(resizedFile) {
            uploadFile(file, resizedFile);
        });
    } else {
        uploadFile(file, file);
    }
  });
};

function uploadFile(originalFile, resizedFile) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'uploadtest.php',
        data: {
            file: resizedFile,
            fileor: Upload.rename(file, $scope.uniqueportrait), //This returns a file
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Here's a fiddle of something similar: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/sL123o7o/1/)